# Getting Max Date for each group using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a  Invoice  table in MYSQL  which have below  data types.
INVOICE :
ID VARCHAR(20)
DATEADD TEXT
STATUS VARCHAR(10)
Data looks  :

```
   ID           DATEADD        STATUS
'A0011'  '04/01/2018 11:58:31'  'N'
'A0011'  '31/05/2019 10:02:36'  'N'
'B0022'  '04/01/2018 11:58:31'  'N'
'B0022'  '31/05/2019 10:02:36'  'N'
'B0022'  '30/04/2020 19:44:36'  'N'
```

Script  :

```
SELECT  ID,MAX(DATEADD)DATEADD,STATUS FROM (
SELECT  ID ,STR_TO_DATE(DATEADD, '%d/%m/%y')DATEADD,STATUS FROM Invoice  WHERE  STATUS = 'N' )T
 GROUP BY  ID, Status;
```

But  I'm not  getting MAX date for the  above data.

Required Out Put :

```
   ID           DATEADD        STATUS
'A0011' '31/05/2019 10:02:36' 'N'
'B0022' '30/04/2020 19:44:36' 'N'
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL 8+` version ? And please never store dates on text fileds

Comment: @ErgestBasha MYSQL 5.7.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MySQL 8+` you can use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
with cte as(
select *,row_number() over(partition by ID order by STR_TO_DATE(DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') desc) as row_num
from Invoice 
) select ID,DATEADD,STATUS
from cte
where row_num =1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=150299f52a7bfa8d06f42d723c648ed6

On Older `MySQL` try:

```
 SELECT ID,  
         DATEADD,
         status
FROM Invoice in1 where (ID,STR_TO_DATE(DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) in ( select ID,                                                  
                                                                                  MAX(STR_TO_DATE(DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'))
                                                                           from  Invoice
                                                                          GROUP BY ID 
                                                                          );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d0344c1eb99de9e00c6410f5b734133